# Engine oil for Honda SH150i

Tags: honda, maintenance, oil-change

I want to change the engine oil of my Honda SH150i scooter model of 2005. What are some different options of oil that I could buy ?

Comment: What does the owners manual say?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don‘t have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a copy of the Owners Manual at:

[Owners Manual](https://ownersmanuals2.com/get/honda-sh150-2012-owners-manual-72043)

On page 78 it says:

SAE 10W-30, API SG, JASO MB

"Suggested": HONDA ‘‘4-STROKE GASOLINE
ENGINE OIL’’ or equivalent.